# ArrayController's property for each item in the model in ember

Tags: ember.js, nsarraycontroller, computed-properties

I've an Array controller which has the property "isChecked" (boolean property). In my controller I want to get the collection of elements which are "checked" (I mean selected). I'm not sure how to access the controller's property in the model.

My controller is as follows:

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isChecked: false,
    totalElements: function()
    {
        return this.model.get('length');
    }.property('@each'),
    selectedElements: function()
    {
        var content = this.get('content');
        console.log(content.filterBy('isChecked'));
        return content.filterBy('isChecked');
    }.property('isChecked'),
});
```

I linked the "isChecked" property to a checkbox inside each helper as follows..

```
<ul>
   {{#each model}}
        <li>
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
            {{name}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I will display all the items in the model with a checkbox associated with it. The user can select few items from it. So I want those items.

[image]

Now I want to get the list of elements which are "checked". Either as a computed property or under any action.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share ur model structure?

Comment: My model just has few properties. I just fetch it from the web and directly return it from the route. I mean I don't save it in the store.

Comment: Is it like [{name:'A', isChecked:true},{name:'B', isChecked:false}] ? And you just want to show the list of checkboxes with isChecked property as true?

Comment: No no.. The model doesn't contain the "isChecked" property at all. I will display all the items. From that the user can 'check' few items. I want those items. I edited the question. May be it'll give you a clear picture now

Comment: If you dont have isChecked property for each select then you have to create. and then use observes('@each.isChecked'), which will trigger whenever your isChecked property gets changed. Now to get the list of selected options you can  create a computed property like you are doing, just filterBy. But main thing is you need isChecked property for each checkbox. The way you are doing is wrong (i.e to have a single isChecked property for all)

Comment: How to create an additional property in the model ? I'm using the response from the webservice directly as a model. From what you say I've to add an property to the model itself. How can I do it ?

Comment: in route afterModel hook you can use forEach method on the model and add one more property. Something like this model.forEach(function(obj){ obj.isChecked = false;});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to move the `isChecked` property onto an `ObjectController`, then reference that controller in the array controller with the `itemController` property.

Array Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'color',

  totalElements: function() {
    return this.get('length');
  }.property('[]'),

  selectedElements: Ember.computed.filterBy('@this', 'isChecked', true)
});
```

(The `@this` means that the computed property will reference the array of item controllers.)

Item Controller:

```
App.ColorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isChecked: false
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tazojejuwi/1/edit

Hope that helps.

Comment: You’re welcome. Just so you know, `ObjectController` will be deprecated in Ember v1.11: http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_objectcontroller

Comment: Then is there any other way I can fix this ? Or should I go with the method mentioned in the comments ?

Comment: i think without the "objectController" it works fine for me. Like what I did in the question. Keeping the "isChecked" property in the arrayController and filtering it by the method you mentioned.

Comment: This will work fine until Ember 2.0. There may be some better instructions to handle the deprecation when 1.11 is released.

Comment: ItemController is deprecated in Ember 1.13.